# Labeling email on compose - Gmail - Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Within my rails app, I am using this gem to interact with the Gmail API: https://github.com/gmailgem/gmail

Here is my method to send an email:

```
email_to = params[:email]
subject_to = params[:subject]

email = gmail.compose do
  to email_to
  subject subject_to
  body "Spent the day on the road..."
  label "Urgent"
end

email.deliver!
```

I am getting this error:

```
undefined method `label' for #<Mail::Message:0x007fb370e94cf8>
```

How do I label an email before sending it with this gem? Is it possible? Should I use another library to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've never used Gmail API but the IMAP protocol has `keywords`. You can use it via [mail gem](https://github.com/mikel/mail) like this:

```
message = Mail.new do
  to 'test@test.com'
  from 'test@test.com'
  keywords 'keyword, "another keyword"'
end
```